# Bootstrap modal does not show with microsoft visual studio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have the following code copy-pasted from [w3schools Modal training page](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp) .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { $("#myBtn").click(function () { $("#myModal").modal('show'); }); });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using MS Visual studio 2019, with Jquery nuget package installed in the project.  I simply copy the code to test it in the razor blank page, execute , then I get nothing apart from the button, when it is clicked , no modal appears.

Nevertheless, **that code works for the online html compilers.**

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Please confirm you *do* get the button?  You're missing some `</div>` which Razor tends to moan at, but would likely not render the whole page.  In the browser press F12 and view the console for errors - maybe your location has the CDN blocked?

Comment: Code updated in the main question section

Comment: As you say, there's nothing wrong with the code provided, it works fine eg in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v28edfkq/) - so there must be some issue with how it's loaded from VS.

Comment: You say you're using jquery nuget, but your html uses CDNs.  You're not using the jquery nuget package.

Comment: Yes I believe so , there is something wrong with the configuration of the porject with VS. 
and that's the heart of the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#myBtn").click(function(){ $("#myModal").modal('show'); }); });
```

Comment: I also tried that but it is not showing the modal .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootstrap custom attribute to trigger the modal like below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```

use `data-toggle` and `data-target` in button tag.

Comment: That works, already tested it . 
The problem here is that I do not know why it does not , with using Jscript.
I actually would need that for further implementations, I need to inject some Ajax to retrieve data from a dynamic nested json file and then show it in the modal .

Comment: do you see any error in the console when clicking on the button?

Comment: Just look at your code look like divs are not nested properly, also try to move the jquery and bootstrap js script CDN link just before the closing body tag and then write your custom jquery code below inside the script tag.

Comment: I have copied verified the nesting of the divs, unfortunately I could see nothing wrong (I re-copied the code again by editing the question - take a look )

Comment: Also, the console is not showing anything . 
Tested with Chrome 104 and Edge .

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code. use `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#YOUR_MODAL_ID"` in the button to make it work.

Here  `YOUR_MODAL_ID=myModal`

> Example using from HTML tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal"
        id="myBtn"
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Example using with Javascript (jQuery)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
        id="myBtn"
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){ $("#myBtn").click(function(){ $("#myModal").modal('show'); }); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Asif, thanks for the answer, I tried that and it works already (see previous answers) , but my problem here , why doesn't it work with Jscript in the first place ?   
I need to implement it with a jscript because I am going to add some ajax in the same script section later .

Comment: I have updated my answer and see the example for using with javascript. Thanks

Comment: Please add a description that explains how your code (the js version) is different from OPs.   They appear to be identical.  Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: Asif, thank you for your interaction, but your code is identical to what has been posted in the question, only a bit beautified.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem solved :

Just added :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now the modal is show upon clicking the button.

The code works on Visual studio and looks like this now :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
                id="myBtn">
            Open Modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button"
                                class="btn btn-default"
                                data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { $("#myBtn").click(function () { $("#myModal").modal('show'); }); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just mark it as your Preferred Answer. Then you do not need other formats, such as bold text to highlight your answer